# Can mongodb geospatial indexing support objects containing more than just lat long arrays?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to geospatially index in mongodb something with a field like this:

```
"geometry": [{"latitude": 84.2, "longitude": 24.2,"time":395384351,"status":"Green"},{"latitude": 84.2, "longitude": 24.2, "time":395384352,"status":"Red"},{"latitude": 84.2, "longitude": 24.2, "time":395384353,,"status":"Blue"}]
```

Or must it be something like this:

```
"geometry": [[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng],[lat,lng]]
```

Is this a yes? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a little test. Here's the data in my geo collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536093e9e3c1d506da48a079"), "loc" : [ 120, 110 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5360940be3c1d506da48a07a"), "loc" : { "lat" : 120, "lng" : 130 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53609422e3c1d506da48a07b"), "loc" : { "latitude" : 120, "lngitude" : 140 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5360942be3c1d506da48a07c"), "loc" : { "latitude" : 120, "lngitude" : 150, "time" : 133232004 } }
```

I made some spell mistakes to make sure the name doesn't matter.
Once I build index with:

```
db.geo.ensureIndex({loc: "2d"});
```

I can now find with $near operator.
As described in the [2d index doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/):

> The values of the array may be either arrays, as in [ 55.5, 42.3 ], or embedded documents, as in { lng : 55.5 , lat : 42.3 }

It turns out it's OK when there are extra fields in the object. As long as the first 2 properties are longitude and latitude. And it gives out the correct result:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.find({loc: {$near: [120, 150]}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5360942be3c1d506da48a07c"), "loc" : { "latitude" : 120, "lngitude" : 150, "time" : 133232004 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53609422e3c1d506da48a07b"), "loc" : { "latitude" : 120, "lngitude" : 140 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5360940be3c1d506da48a07a"), "loc" : { "lat" : 120, "lng" : 130 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536093e9e3c1d506da48a079"), "loc" : [ 120, 110 ] }
```

What's more, when you have 2d index on the field, it will prevent you from inserting invalid data like:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.insert({loc: {str: "string", latitude: 120, lngitude: 140, time: 133232004}} );
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16804,
        "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 16804 location object expected, location array not in correct format"
    }
})
```

**However**, as the index always accept the 1st field as longitude, and 2nd field as latitude. Your data doesn't seem to satisfy the requirement.